# Euphemism for "non-useful"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, negation, euphemisms, litotes

I was just about to tell someone how something "wouldn't really be much useful" if they leave it the way it is — which is like a much more polite version of *useless*, but I just couldn't find the word. I'm guessing I just don't know it.

What is an idiomatic euphemism for *non-useful*?

**EDIT:**

It was actually an answer to a question, and I was wondering how I would say this answer is not really useful without hurting the person.

Comment: Something that is *futile* or done *in vain?*

Comment: I thought of that too, but futile and vain seem worse, no?

Comment: @OP: Depends on your context. I'm upvoting *ineffective* !

Comment: non-essential? as in 'non-essential personnel'.

Comment: “not much useful” isn't grammatically correct, by the way. You mean “not much use” or “not very useful”.

Comment: *For what its worth / for whatever its worth* can help in communicating the sense of ' sure, but don't expect miracles'

Comment: On a different note, suggesting that an answer is 'not useful' may not serve much purpose. Rather, you should explain why you think it is of no use, and let the answerer get your point.

Comment: Would it be terrible to say, you're useless? I think it's to the point and very easy to understand.

Comment: @WillHunting: One of the potential problems in the English community I have noticed is too much editing. But I would be lying if I claim that all answers here have not been useful. FumbleFingers answered it excellently well and I agreed quite all right I was looking for a euphemism on the first edit.

Comment: This questions remind me of a Quote from Harry M. Schey in the 4th Edition of Div, Grad, Curl, and All That: An Informal Text on Vector Calculus: The word "Formal" in this context is a euphemism for "useless”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this list of British "euphemisms"](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2011/05/euphemistically_speaking)...

> *"**Very interesting**"* means *"I don't agree/I don't believe you"*

(the hapless American assumes the Brit means *"I am impressed"*, so the euphemism has worked!). But I personally think it's a good way of saying *"Although what you say is **interesting**, and might be useful in some other context, it has **no practical value** in relation to my current problem."*

Older Americans may recall [Rowan & Martin's Laugh-In](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arte_Johnson), featuring the catchphrase

> ["Very interesting ... but stupid!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQyUKnCf0YY)

Comment: Nice one, but definitely not something you will use with a *respected person*...

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: Of course you can. If your boss comes along and starts advising you in great detail how you should tackle some problem, you might know that what he's saying is worthless, and that you'll completely ignore his advice once he gets out of the way and lets you get on with things. But you might well say *"Thanks for the advice, it was very interesting"* if you can't bring yourself to lie outright and say *"Thanks for the advice, which I'm sure I will find useful"*.

Comment: Haha, you have a very interesting personality @FumbleFingers, my boss did detect it outright, so it'll be like another dark bazooka behind curtains :)

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: Ah. Sounds like your boss has a fine-tuned [{bull}shit-detector](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullshit%20detector), so you can't safely use well-established euphemisms. Just tell him his help was *"useful"*, and tell yourself that if it had *really* been any help, you'd have said it was *"**really** useful"*. Unless he checks you out here on ELU, he'll never catch on.

Comment: Nice link to British euphemisms +1

Comment: @JAM: I particularly like the distinction between British *"QUITE good" (with the stress on the "quite")* and *"quite GOOD" (with the stress on the "good ")*. Both understood by Americans to mean *"quite good"*, but in reality the first one means *"a bit disappointing"*, whereas the second means *"excellent"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - and somewhat predictably, this Canadian and her Glaswegian spouse recognized about half of the euphemisms, while the rest seemed quite opaque to one or both of us.

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer to this question, ineffective sounds too strong on a second thought...

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: Yes - I think the whole point of a "euphemism" is that it should "soften" the truth - but not to the point where it's effectively a blatant lie. As you imply, *ineffective* is far too "direct" to be called a euphemism at all (I don't understand how a majority of voters can consider it in any way indirect / tactful / courteous). But you don't have to know the old *...but stupid!* follow-up to imagine *...but [**something**]*, even if it's never explicitly stated.

Comment: Well, that's one idea.

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate euphemism for "completely useless but still quite nice" is *entirely decorative*. See for example its use on [Wikipedia, for Dutch Gable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_gable) and [this review of some headphones](http://hometheaterreview.com/akg-k44-closed-back-studio-headphones/).

**Edit:** Another option might be *well-intentioned*.  This would even be applicable for the edited version of this question; that is, the "useless" thing is an answer to a question.

Comment: Sorry, David - this seems totally off target to OP's request.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Right, I didn't see the edit.  I answered the question the way it was at the time that I saw the question.  The edit changes the question somewhat.  Thanks for explaining your downvote though; much better than a hit-and-run.

Comment: Ouch! I tried to undo the downvote but am now locked out.  If you edit your answer i can take it back!

Comment: It's OK, @KristinaLopez, I don't really care about the downvote.  If I think of a good answer to the edited question, I will edit the answer accordingly.  But right now, I can't think of such a term.

Answer (score 5):

"This answer doesn't suit (or doesn't fit) my needs."  In my opinion, this puts the perception of shortcoming on my needs instead of their answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Not exactly the thing" or "not quite it".

Answer (score 2):

In the context of addressing an answer, I think it's fine to be direct (no need to be euphemistic or use a substitute word like "interesting"), as long as you do it politely. You don't have to use the word "useless" but don't hide what you are trying to say either behind a word that does not mean what you are actually trying to say. The exact wording would depend upon the question asked and the answer given, but some examples might look like:

> I appreciate the input, but unfortunately that doesn't work in this
>   case.

or

> Thanks, but I don't think that can be applied to this problem.

As long as you thank them for trying and acknowledge that what they offered was a fair attempt at helping, they probably will not be offended/upset/hurt that it happens to not be useful to your particular circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

"Thanks, that's certainly the most recent answer I've received."

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answers the question. In general, we're looking for answers that, at the very least, have some explanation and, where relevant, citations to resources such as dictionaries or style guides.

Comment: I was suggesting that as a polite way to thank and acknowledge someone for their contribution, even if it is not a helpful one. The person asked the question seemed to be concerned about being subtle/gentle.

Comment: OK, but it doesn't seem at all polite, to me. Highlighting some irrelevant point about the answer (e.g., the time or the nice font it was written in) seems to be pretty directly saying that there was nothing at all worthwhile about it. I suppose one could say that it's euphemistic (which doesn't necessarily imply polite) but the question does ask for something that's idiomatic as well, and I don't think this is that.

Answer (score 0):

One of these days I'm going to surprise you by making use of your gems of wisdom.
Your excellent advice has been duly noted.
Wait, I'm just going to write it all down.